# Is there a way to set a pointer struct field to a pointer pointing to the Zero value of that pointer type using reflect?

Tags: go, go-reflect

That was a mouthful of a title, let me explain more. Assuming I have a struct of all pointers (don't know of what type)

```
type A struct {
  S *string
  I *int
}
```

I want to write a function that takes a pointer to that struct and given a `fieldName` sets that field to a pointer to the Zero/empty value of that pointer. For example:

```
func setZeroForField(i any, fieldName string) {
  // do stuff
}

a := A{}
setZeroForField(&a, "S")
setZeroForField(&a, "I")

// *a.S == ""
// *a.I == 0
```

Is there any way to do it using reflect? I know how to get the types of the fields of `A` but I can't use `reflect.Indirect` because it just returns a Zero value which in this case is a nil pointer, not the empty string or 0.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
func setZeroForField(i any, fieldName string) {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(i).Elem()
    fv := rv.FieldByName(fieldName)
    fv.Set(reflect.New(fv.Type().Elem()))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/7clmztF5uaa